# How to skew a progressbar?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar, skew

I want to set a android progressbar that looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION:**

In the end I was able to achieve the desired result by using a nine-patch imageView and changing the width of this imageView relative to its container. The container reflects the maxiumum (100%) size of the progressbar.

**What I've already tried:**

**Use Android's skew method**

```
progressBar.matrix.setSkew(1f, 0.5f)
```

Nothing happens, the progressbar still looks like a standard progressbar.
I also tried

```
progressBar.matrix.postSkew(1f, 0.5f),
```

tried to use other values for setSkew and postSkew and tried to

```
progressbar.invalidate()
```

after setting the skew.

**Use custom progressBar.progressDrawable**

I also considered using a custom progressDrawable, but did not know how to achieve the desired look.

**Reason:** The Background of the progressbar has to be transparent, so I can't just have overlapping rectangles as considered, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564304/android-draw-shape-with-skewed-corner).

Is there a way to make one of the approaches explained above work, or maybe another way to achieve the expected result?

Expected Result:

[image: skewed progressbar]

Actual Result:

[image: regular progressbar]

Comment: `Reason: The Background of the progressbar has to be transparent` What stops you from using a **transparent** PNG? Better, if using a 9 patch? OR even a VectorDrawable?

Comment: I tried using a 9 patch and also transparent PNG. They work quite fine, except that the skewed end of the progressbar is not shown until the progress is completed.

Comment: Then there's something wrong in the implementation. All the graphical elments should be redrawn continously. Try invalidating the view after drawing onto it, so to refresh it.

Comment: I tried invalidating the view, but i still got the same result. I think this is because the android progressbar does not really scale the drawable according to the progress, but instead clips the non-visible part of the drawable.

Comment: ... if that wouldn't cut out the non-visible end cap

Comment: For me, this is a perfect use case for a 9 patch. But 9 patches require a deep understanding of how they do work. It's very easy, but it must be clearly acquired. Or you will get stretching where you don't want it.

Comment: Your hint with the nine-patch was very valuable, thanks! In my working solution, instead of using it as the drawable of a progressbar, I used it as a regular imageView. I scaled this imageView relative to the width of its container, which represents the maximum possible progress(100%). This worked pretty fine.

Comment: Nice to hear that you were able to work it out.